# Class selector not able to style img tags whereas ID selector is able to style the same image?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-selectors

I was trying to style an image with a class selector and it was not working. When I applied apply the same style using an ID selector, it worked fine.

Can anyone check what I'm doing wrong? That class selector is not able to style the img:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="Card">
      <img ClassName="poster" alt="xyz" src="images/song.jpg" />
      <div ClassName="audio-details">
        <p ClassName="audio-name"></p>
        <p ClassName="artist-name"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The CSS attached to this:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.Card {
  background-color: red;
}

.poster {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

The CSS file is connected properly, I was able to style the image if used an id selector instead of class selector.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that jumps out is you should be using `className` not `ClassName` (lowercase 'c' at the start, uppercase 'N'). Try that and see if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to case sensitive issue , use 'className' instead of Classname for all the element under card div element.